# Can't recognise the tap on UILabel which is out of bounds of the parent view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a situation:

```
            -------------
            |           |
-------------------------
| UILabel               |
-------------------------
            | UIView    |
            |           |
            -------------
```

I need to check if user tap on UILabel. UILabel is a subview of UIView.

```
result.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
textLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[result addSubview: textLabel];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action: @selector(reportTap:)];
tapRecognizer.delaysTouchesBegan = YES;
[textLabel addGestureRecognizer: tapRecognizer];
```

So the tap is recognised only on UIView, I tried to override `- (UIView *) hitTest: (CGPoint)point withEvent: (UIEvent *)event` but it was never called, tried to add tapRecognizer to UILabel ==> that's not solve the problem too. Any help?

Comment: which hitTest did you override? the label or the current view? even if you add tapRecognizer to uilabel it is still out of bounds so it will not register

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully this will help you.

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

BOOL isInside = [super pointInside:point withEvent:event];

// identify the label view subclass
UILabel * textLabel = (UILabel *)[result viewWithTag:1];
CGPoint inLabelSpace = [self convertPoint:point toView:textLabel];

BOOL isInsideLabel = [textLabel pointInside:inLabelSpace withEvent:nil];

if (YES == isInsideLabel) {

    return isInsideLabel;

} // if (YES == isInsideLabel)


return isInside;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you invoke `[label sizeToFit]`?
if so , your situation might look like this

```
            -------------
            |           |
------------
| UILabel   |           |
------------
            | UIView    |
            |           |
            -------------
```

post your label's frame and check if it's right or not.

Answer (score 0):

When you create new view, you can pass as parameter - instance of a parent, and then add this label to parent instance, either to this view or add tap recognizer to parent when adding view;
For example

```
    UIView *childView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.tableView.bounds.origin.y, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT-64)];

    UIlabel *label = [UILabel alloc] init];
    [childView addSubview:label];
    [self.view addSubview:childView];



    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                              action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    [childView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    tap.delegate = self;
```